# Why won't Scala parser combinators propagate failure inside a repeated (rep) clause?

Tags: scala, parser-combinators

If I have simple parser defs like this:

```
  def term: Parser[String] = """[a-zA-Z"']+""".r ^^ { _.toString }
  def intWhole: Parser[String] = wholeNumber ^^ { w => w }

  def simpleTerm: Parser[String] = term >> { 
    case t:String => failure("Oops!") 
  }
```

If I parse against simpleTerm (with any string) it fails as expected with my "Oops!" message.

Now if I add this:

```
  def repTerm: Parser[Unit] = rep(simpleTerm | intWhole) ^^ { _ => Unit }
```

If I now parse against repTerm, again with just a non-numeric character string, what I'd hope to happen is have it fail with the same "Oops!" message--basically an aborted parse.  What happens instead is that I get no error at all; just the returned Unit.

Is there a way to make parsing stop once it hits a failure, and return that failure, during a rep() clause?

Answer (score 0):

Looked at the code.  There's a difference how rep() handles failure vs errors.  failure() just tells a repeating sequence to stop, i.e. end of repeating clause.  It's not a breakage necessarily.  err() means something broke, and a rep() clause does propagate errors and stop further parsing.

Changing my failure() in code above to err() produces the desired result of stopping further parsing.